# many 00000 zeros after number message Approvals Share point list Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, formula, power-automate

[column list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQCld.png)Why data from the List Share Point is displayed with many zeros. The data format in the column in the list with which I take data has these parameters:
The data type returned from this formula is Number (1, 1.0, 100).
The type of information in this column is  Calculated (calculation based on other columns)

I add screenshot

[image: 2]

I want to display "13" not "13.000000000000"
[flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPelW.png)
[floow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY40r.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [int](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#int) function to convert the string into a number.

Let's assume you are retrieving the list item with a Get Item action and the column is named Leave Days. In that scenario you could use an expression like below:

```
int(outputs('Get_item')?['body/Leave_x0020_Days'])
```

Comment: I did so, but an error appears. how can i fix this?
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Start_and_wait_for_an_approval' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'int' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type.'.

Comment: Sorry, I was expecting it was a string value. Maybe it isn't. Can you try `int(string(outputs('Get_item')?['body/Leave_x0020_Days']))` to see if that makes a difference?

Btw, can you also share a screenshot of your flow setup? This might help the troubleshooting.

Comment: I saw that you need to use 'Get item' and I use 'Get items', now I have an error with the ID in 'Get item', wow I'm confused

I have a Leaves list where a new leave request appears.
I also have a Balance list, which calculates the number of free days.

When a new request is created in the Leaves list, I send Approval where in the text of the message I want to see information from the Balance list. Here is my flow - I added the flow to the main message.

Comment: In see in your screenshot the leave balance is within an apply to each. Try something like below instead
`int(string(item()?['Leave_x0020_Days']))`